# Does Facebook prefetch linked urls when shown on userwall?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, access-log

I have a blog article published on our website and i posted a link to it on our facebook site. Lot of people click this article on their facebook-wall.

Now there is a big difference when comparing the number of requests of this article between google analytics and what i am counting with an access-log analyzer. It's about factor 10!

Does someone know where this big difference may come from? The requests in the access log are no bot-requests. They all have different and common user-agents and are most from different IPs.

Could it be that facebook is prefetching the linked URLs to display the link on the userwall?

Comment: Fire up your browser’s dev tools and find  out …?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Facebook is prefetching the page. This article explains things very well: http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/magento-website-hammering-facebook-liger/